# glBlendEquation(GL_MIN) replacement in OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I've search around and seems that glBlendEquation has some [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841763/android-gles20-glblendequation-not-working) in Android, -GL_MAX/MIN is not even listed in the opengles [specs](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/)

I need to find a workaround to GL_MIN blendEquation mode. Is that possible? I want to write to a color buffer only if the alpha there is greater than the pixel's alpha i'm trying to write. Is it possible to do it without any extension or using more than 1 texture?

Comment: Ok... i went for the easy-dirty-inefficient solution!

Answer (score 0):

The dirty solution I was trying to avoid is this. Using Frame Buffer objects and shaders to emulate the color buffer and the blending mode:

```
Modify existing shaders to blend the scene with an FBO_1, into FBO_2.
Render FBO_2 to the screen.
```

The next drawing call swap FBO_1 with FBO_2, as FBO_2 equals the color buffer.

An "unintrusive" and more inefficient alternative is to use 3 FBOs and a shader, and make an additional pass.

```
Render scene to FBO_1 //without any modification to existing shaders
Blend FBO_1 with FBO_2 into FBO_3 //with new shader.
Render FBO_3 to the screen.
```

The next drawing call swap FBO_2 with FBO_3. The only advantage of this alternative is that i dont have to modify the existing drawing logic.

I really don't like any of this ideas. I'll gladly accept better answers!